# No adapter attached; skipping layout in android

Tags: android

But error messages are being logged:

15:25:53.476 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

15:25:53.655 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: You have not added adapter in recyclerview. so, this is the reason why you are getting above logs.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs at the moment when the RecyclerView tries to render itself, but does not have an adapter attached to it. It's not a critical error usually.

FIX: Try to attach the empty adapter to RecyclerView in onCreate / onViewCreated (for fragments):

```
//declare list with items to display 
private final List<POJOItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

//declare adapter 
Recyclerview adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items)
//attach adapter 
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Even if List/ArrayList is empty you attached adapter and error should stop displaying.
You can add data to the array at every moment after attaching the adapter

Comment: Thx men, your answer helped me to resolve my problem, thx again